# Heirloom-mailx and Saving to IMAP Folder with Spaces

Tags: email, imap, mailx

If I try to save to a message to an IMAP folder with the command `save 1 +FOLDER/"Folder withSpaces"` in heirloom-mailx, instead of saving, mailx spits out `No applicable messages from {Folder/"Folder, withSpaces"}`. For folders without spaces, it successfully appends the message to the folder, as desired. Can anyone offer me a clue as to why this is, so that I may fix it? I've googled, but have been unsuccessful in finding an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To quote from the [mailx manpage](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx/mailx.1.html#14):

> - An argument can be enclosed between paired double-quotes `""` or single-quotes `''`; any white space, shell word expansion, or backslash characters within the quotes are treated literally as part of the argument. A double-quote will be treated literally within single-quotes and vice versa. **These special properties of the quote marks occur only when they are paired at the beginning and end of the argument.** [*emphasis added*]

So quotes in the middle of an argument don't work (unlike most shells).  But you can't say `"+FOLDER/Folder withSpaces"` either, because the manpage also says:

> - If the filename begins with an **unquoted** plus sign, and the folder variable is defined, the plus sign will be replaced by the value of the folder variable followed by a slash. [*emphasis added*]

So if you use quotes, the `+` won't be special anymore.  You'll have to fall back to backslash escaping:

```
save 1 +FOLDER/Folder\ withSpaces
```

ought to work.  (Actually, I'm not *certain* that `"+FOLDER/Folder withSpaces"` won't work; you might try it just to see if I've misinterpreted the manpage.)

You might consider renaming the folder, say to `Folder_withUnderscore` or `Folder-withHyphen`.

Comment: Unfortunately, escaping the space (rather than quoting) does not work: it spits out the error "Referencing beyond EOF". Strangely, folder navigation isn't hindered by spaces: I can escape the space or use quotes for just the foldername with spaces or use quotes around the whole argument, and all work. I might have to rename the folder to eliminate the space.

Comment: @Sara, that sounds like a bug in mailx.  You might try reporting it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've e-mailed the developer, and will update this thread once I have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looking more at the mailx manpage, I noticed the `shortcut` command, which accomplishes exactly what I wanted. I made a shortcut to the "All Mail" folder in Gmail, e.g. `shortcut all "+[Gmail]/All Mail"`, and then `save 1 all` appends the message to the "All Mail" folder, as desired.